# How to Auto increment column when using merge and in not matching case - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, merge

Want to add a incremental number in MERGE when the NOT MATCHED case.

It only allows to write insert statements, I tried to set the value using the MAX() function too, but adds the same number to all the records.

What is expected

```
MERGE #targetTable AS [target]
USING #sourceTable AS [source] ON [target].key = [source].key

WHEN MATCHED
    UPDATE ROWS
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (id, Name)
   VALUES ([incremented_id], source.Name);
```

Note : Table already have some records in it.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If your destination has id column as Identity (1,1) it will insert auto increment id's. and you do not need to include that in merge statement

Comment: The table doesn't have that for that id column its just a plain int.

Comment: Could you do something like: `VALUES (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by source.name) + (SELECT max(id) FROM target), source.Name);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to get max ID from the table and then add it to this parameter. With this select you will be creating a new id of every row that is inserted. Something like this should work

```
     declare @root int = 64895
     WHEN MATCHED
     UPDATE ROWS
     WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT (id, Name)
     VALUES( ((@root - 1) + ROW_NUMBER() over(order by ID)), source.Name);
```